# Mysql threads: объясните поведение, не могу найти узкое место

Tags: производительность, php, config, configuration, mysql

Есть php-приложение (lighttpd + php-fpm + mysql). Когда на сайт заходит много пользователей (около 3000), поведение mysql становится следующим (приведу данные mysqladmin status):

Состояние 1. Сначала все работает нормально: *Threads: 58  Questions: 462874  Slow queries: 3  Opens: 631  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 624  Queries per second avg: 1081.481*

Состояние 2. По мере нарастания и достижения пиковой нагрузки происходит следующее: *Threads: 4  Questions: 737449  Slow queries: 3  Opens: 635  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 628  Queries per second avg: 1258.445*

В "состоянии 2" к mysql невозможно подключится, и сайт вываливается в 500. Он как-будто захлебывается от происходящего и отказывается работать. =) После того как пользователей становится меньше, mysql оживает и возвращается к "состоянию 1", начинают создаваться потоки, и все работает хорошо.

Почему происходят падения количества потоков и самого mysql в пиковый момент, понять не могу, причем когда потоков становится мало, все они (все 4) находятся в режиме sleep.

Я понимаю, что я не описал всю архитектуру приложения, но, насколько я понимаю, узкое место именно mysql или соединение с ним. Mysql настроен адекватно, если же дело в настройке, прошу дать знать, куда обратить свое внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С мускулем не знаю, но другие приложения при сильной нагрузке ведут себя похоже. Вначале все нарастает, нарастает, а потом наступает "провал". Причина проста. Любое приложение не целостное, а состоит из "блоков". Например, блок приема соединений, блок парсинга, блок обработки. 
Логично, что блок приема соединений может набрать больше, чем блок выборки данных с базы. Поэтому, в начальный момент пиковой нагрузки начальные "блоки" набирают по максимуму, а последующие блоки не могут обработать. Следовательно, начальные блоки перестают принимать данные (я бы сказал, что они работают в режиме "насыщения").
Позже, когда нагрузка падает, набранные данные нужно обработать. Соответственно, ещё какое то время наблюдается нагрузка и потом потихоньку спадает.

Поэтому, наблюдая за данными о состоянии мускуля, нужно понимать, что именно видим.

Из этого всего следует, что нужно искать слабое место. К примеру, им может быть сеть (а сеть - это также блок - блок передачи данных), которая при пиковой нагрузке она может не смочь (к примеру, стоит дешевый роутер, который при определенной нагрузке начинает глючить).
Возможно и другое - все запросы возвращают большие наборы данных. А реально используется пара записей. Или много одинаковых запросов. В этом случае хорошо помогает memcache.
Также слабым местом может быть вставка данных. В мускуля есть два типа таблиц - mysam и innodb. Для одного типа вставка одной записи блокирует всю таблицу (и другие вставки в этот момент не проходят), в другом случае блокировки построчные (какой именно тип за что отвечает - это лучше прогуглить).
А ещё бывает полезно настроить master-slave и поставить ещё один мускуль-сервер в пару к существующему.

Answer (score 1):

Узким место оказалась сеть. Пользователи забивали канал, и до mysql просто не доходило, поэтому количество потоков падало. Всем спасибо.